# Using INDEX-MATCH to look for values in two columns and returning a third value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a matrix of sorts, where column A has a list of parts and the Row 1 is populated with weeks of the year in yyyy/mm format. What I am trying to do is populate this matrix with quantity data from an aggregate sheet, where the demand quantities for each part is listed by week of the year. In this aggregate sheet, column A lists the parts, column B lists the weeks, and column C lists the quantities.

I've been trying to write an `=INDEX(MATCH(),MATCH())` type of formula in order to fetch the value of column C if the values from Columns A & B match the values in Column A and Row 1 respectively on the matrix sheet, but have been only getting #REF errors in return. At this point I need a second pair of eyes. Here is the formula:

`=INDEX(MRP!$C$1:$C$6400,MATCH(A2,MRP!$A$2:$A$6400,0),MATCH(B1,MRP!$B$2:$B$6400,0))`

Am I going about this the right way, or is another method needed instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell B2
    =SUMIFS(MRP!$C:$C,MRP!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A3,MRP!$B:$B,Sheet1!B$1)

You can then copy these down and across.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `#REF` error because you are out of range of the array you are trying to match. The index function takes two arguments and one optional argument.

```
INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num])
```

Looking at your formula,

```
=INDEX(MRP!$C$1:$C$6400,MATCH(A2,MRP!$A$2:$A$6400,0),MATCH(B1,MRP!$B$2:$B$6400,0))
```

- `MRP!$C$1:$C$6400` is the array to be matched
- `MATCH(A2,MRP!$A$2:$A$6400,0)` gets the row number. Maybe it should be `MATCH(A1....)`?
- `MATCH(B1,MRP!$B$2:$B$6400,0)` gets the column number.

But since your matching array only have one column, the column number from the match function is greater than 1, which is outside the range of the array.

If you need to match both values in column A and B, you can use this formula to match

```
=MATCH(lookup_value_1 & lookup_value_2, lookup_array_1 & lookup_array_2, match_type)
```

For you case, it would be

```
=MATCH(A1 & B1, MRP!$A$2:$A$6400 & MRP!$B$2:$B$6400, 0)
```

you'll need to commit your formula using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` rather than just pressing `Enter`. This will get you the row number where both col A and B matches cell `A1` and `B1`.

Finally, you can index it

```
=INDEX(MRP!$C$1:$C$6400,Result from above match,0)
```

Comment: This feels close, although I'm still getting a `#NA` error with the first step of the formula you recommended (even after committing with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`).

Breaking the formula down to just `INDEX(MATCH())`, I get this:
`=INDEX(MRP!C2:C6400,MATCH(A2,MRP!A2:A6400,0))` returns the first quantity value listed for that part.
`=INDEX(MRP!C2:C6400,MATCH(B1,MRP!B2:B6400,0))` returns the first quantity value listed for that yyyy/ww date. The ultimate goal is to refine the search so I get the specific quantity for that part on that specific yyyy/ww date.

Comment: try this line `=MATCH(A1 & B1, MRP!$A$2:$A$6400 & MRP!$B$2:$B$6400, 0)`. It is meant to get exactly what you are looking for, the line that matches both criteria.

Comment: I'm still getting a `#VALUE` error (which turns into `#N/A` with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`).

Comment: `=INDEX(MRP!$C$1:$C$6400,MATCH(A1 & B1, MRP!$A$2:$A$6400 & MRP!$B$2:$B$6400, 0),0)` is that what you did? Do you see the `{}` around this code after you do `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`? Make sure your data is already present in those columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would use SUMIFS. Create a helper column in your second sheet with the month number in and then use

```
=SUMIFS(sheet2!column C, sheet 2!helper column, month(sheet1!A$1),sheet2! column A, sheet1!$A1)
```